# Measuring a voltage that is higher than your reference voltage

Tags: adc, voltage-measurement, voltage-reference

Question: How to measure an input power rail?

Let's say I want to build a circuit that switches in a load that draws 1A from a 5V power rail (that is the supply for the device) and then measures that rail to see if it droops and if so by how much. This seems like a chicken and egg problem as you obviously can't use the 5V as a reference. I have little practical experience with ADCs but suspect that if this is solvable a band gap reference will play a part. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Use a Zener diode as a voltage reference (which is a type of a band gap reference AFAIK).

Comment: One needs a voltage reference to measure a voltage, and having a bandgap voltage reference available contradicts the terms of the question! Widely used in integrated circuits, a bandgap reference produces a constant voltage irrespective of power supply variations, temperature changes and the loading on the device. Usually it has an output voltage around 1.25 V, close to the theoretical 1.22 eV bandgap of silicon at 0 K. See the circuit here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Band_gap_reference.

Comment: right, so I can see how a bandgap voltage reference could be used as a reliable upper limit for an ADC, but what if the voltage you want to measure is higher than that? The wiki link states: " Usually it has an output voltage around 1.25 V". Lets say your Vref is 1.25. How do you reliably measure voltages higher than that? I may be revealing my ignorance on how ADCs work, but there you go.

Comment: title edited to clarify the question

Comment: If the voltage you need to measure is higher than your bandgap, then you use a voltage divider to lower the voltage you are measuring. Buffer if needed with a precision op-amp.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose you have an ADC with a reference equal to the supply voltage you're trying to measure (5.0V in this case).

If you use an LM431 shunt 2.495V reference (that's a cheap one, there are ones with much tighter tolerances available) with a resistor you can calculate the supply voltage. Call the 2.495V input Vx

Since (for a 10-bit ADC) ADC_count = 1024 * Vx/Vref, we can calculate

Vref = 1024*Vx/ADC_Count. This will give a result with 9-bit resolution (accuracy will depend on how accurate your Vx is).

So if Vx = 2.490 and your ADC_Count is 0x212, then the supply voltage/reference is 4.81V.

If you don't like having to calculate the reciprocal, you can operate the ADC with a reference that is regulated and divide down the supply voltage so that is within the ADC range. This would also give more resolution if you don't divide it as much as 2:1.

You can also connect the LM431 with two resistors to give you (say) a 4.0V nominal Vx, which will also improve the resolution. Or use another reference with a higher output voltage (4.096V references are available).

Comment: Some system on chip microprocessors don't allow you to supply the ADC voltage separately. Your first idea is a good trick to overcome that problem. It turns the whole thing on its ear. Thanks! I will probably use that trick, possibly in the very near future.

Comment: Many/most microcontrollers with ADCs already include a bandgap reference, so you don't need the external reference - or even, if 5v is your MCU's supply voltage - the resistor divider!

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, it's desired to measure the same supply rail from which the ADC is powered.  (?)

One common solution is to measure a stable reference voltage *V<sub>2</sub>* with respect to varying *V<sub>cc</sub>*, rather than deriving a lower voltage from varying *V<sub>cc</sub>* and measuring it with respect to stable voltage reference.

Create a stable reference voltage *V<sub>2</sub> < V<sub>cc</sub>*, but not use it as a ADC's voltage reference.  Use *V<sub>cc</sub>* as ADC's voltage reference and measure *V<sub>2</sub>* with respect to *V<sub>cc</sub>*.  If *V<sub>2</sub>* is stable and *V<sub>cc</sub>* is dropping, the ADC measurement for *V<sub>2</sub>* will increase.

Answer (score 0):

The droop measured in volts when 1A is drawn is numerically equal to the output resistance in ohms of the 5V supply; for a regulated supply that will likely be a few milliohms. If the 1A load is continually switched at a low frequency the task can be done by measuring the peak-to-peak voltage swing on the supply, which can be done with highest accuracy by an ac coupled scope or a synchronous detector.